# How to catch network failures while invoking get() method through Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, webdriver

I am using Chrome with selenium and the test run well, until suddenly internet/proxy connection is down, then browser.get(url) get me this:
[image]

If I reload the page 99% it will load fine, what is the proper way to handle this ?

MY CODE:

```
def web_adress_navigator(browser, link):
"""Checks and compares current URL of web page and the URL to be navigated and if it is different, it does navigate"""

try:
    current_url = browser.current_url
except WebDriverException:
    try:
        current_url = browser.execute_script("return window.location.href")
    except WebDriverException:
        current_url = None

if current_url is None or current_url != link:
    retries = 5
    while retries > 0:
        try:
            browser.get(link)
            break
        except TimeoutException:
            logger.warning('TimeoutException when tring to reach page')
            retries -= 1
            while not is_connected():
                sleep(60)
                logger.warning('there is no valid connection')
```

I am not getting into TIMEOUT EXCEPTION but to the break part.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question and your code trials as you are trying to access the *url* passed through the argument **`link`** you can adapt a strategy where:

- Your program will make pre-defined number of trials to invoke the desired *url*, which you can pass through `range()`.
- Once you invoke `get(link)` your program will invoke [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for a predefined interval for the *url to contain* a pre-defined `partialURL` from the *url*.
- You can handle this code within a `try{}` block with [expected_conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) method [title_contains()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892345/selenium-is-not-properly-determining-if-a-page-has-a-title-html-tag/53895407#53895407) and in case of `TimeoutException` invoke `browser.get(link)` again within the `catch{}` block.
- Your modified code block will be:

  ```
  #imports
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
  # other code works
  browser.get(link)
  for i in range(3):
      try:
          WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.title_contains(partialTitle))
          break
      except TimeoutException:
          browser.get(link)
  logger.warning('there is no valid connection')
  ```

Comment: I don't get you, the url for the fail example is the url in "link" var, so in this case it will not refresh! or am I missing something ?

Comment: Maybe it will be best to wait on some part of the title?
EC.title_contains('Amazon')

Comment: As you are having the _argument_ **link**, you can consider to set _partialLinkText_ to **link** (but preferably partial link). If the _partialLinkText_ is not found once the navigation completes (due to network problems), `catch{}` will retry the _url_. Let me know if that answers your question. Ofcoarse you can validate as per _Page Title_ as well.

Comment: I am really sorry I don't get what partialLinkText is. I tried to find out in google but came but confused.

Comment: My bad, I have used the wrong nomenclature. I have changed the verbatim from `partialLinkText` to **partialURL** . For example if the complete _url_ is `https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/`, **partialURL**s are **`docs`**, **`seleniumhq`**, **`org`** and **`download`**. Let know if this answers your question.

Comment: I don't see how that help, since going to www.google.com  will bring me title "google" that will detected as false.

Comment: I did take you solution but chcking the title is not an url by it self:
def find_url(string):
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
    o = urlparse(string)
    if hasattr(o, 'netloc') and hasattr(o, 'scheme') and o.netloc != '':
        return True
    return False

Comment: Check the `expected_conditions` method [**`url_contains(url)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.url_contains)

Comment: @SionC I did a mini research over your usecase and as you mentioned earlier in your comment  `ExpectedCondition` method **`titleContains()`** seems to be best fit. I have updated my answer accordingly. Let me know your thoughts about it.