# Selenium is not properly determining if a page has a <title> html tag

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, page-title

I'm trying to get Selenium to wait until the title tag of a web page is present when loading with Python.

I've tried testing this code with other types of HTML tags and only the `<body>` tag didn't result in an error.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(link)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'div')))
```

I expected the code to evaluate to completion but I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Does that page actually have any `div` elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `title` tag is never *visible*. You can wait for its *presence*, though:

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'title')))
```

The title also has its own expected conditions, `title_is()` and `title_contains()`. For example:

```
wait.until(EC.title_is("Google"))
```

You can review the complete list of supported expected conditions in the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions).

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for the help! This definitely was a head-scratcher; I should have payed much more attention to the actual meaning of the method's name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the *Page Title* locating the `<title>` tag is not the ideal way.

To print the title you need to induce *WebDriverWait* either for either of the following expected_conditions:

- [`title_contains(partial_title)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.title_contains)
- [`title_is(title)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.title_is)
- An example:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("G"))
  print("Page title is: %s" %(driver.title))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Page title is: Google
  ```