# Python Selenium TypeError: argument of type 'TimeoutException' is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, timeout

I'm running Python Selenium Script, and sometimes, when the internet connexion is not working i got 2 types of errors :

```
timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000

unknown error: net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

So i want to make this; each time one of those 2 errors appears, run another script i have on my laptop

Here is the concerned part of my code:

```
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            line_count += 1
            if "Timed out" in e:
                os.system(r"C:\Users\SAMSUNG\script.py")
                print("Done")
                pass
            else:
                print("Not Concerned Error")
                pass

            if "ERR_PROXY" in e:
                os.system(r"C:\Users\SAMSUNG\script.py")
                print("Done")
                pass
            else:
                print("Not Concerned Error")
                pass
```

**But it doesn't work! Here is my error:**

```
if "Timed out" in e:
TypeError: argument of type 'TimeoutException' is not iterable
```

Comment: I think you're going to find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955896/how-to-catch-network-failures-while-invoking-get-method-through-selenium-and-p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the `Exception` instance to a string first:

```
if "Timed out" in str(e):
```

If you are going to be doing multiple checks, then do the conversion once:

```
str_e = str(e)
...
if "Timed out" in str_e:
...
if "ERR_PROXY" in str_e:
```